# How do I add a link to a menu from a module in Drupal 6?

Tags: theming, routes, hooks

I'm creating a drop down menu with nice menus, but I'm having a problem programatically adding a link to the menu from modules. I have defined the menu in the Administration section under Site Building > Menus and can get it to work fine if I add a link manually, but I can't get any links from modules to show up. Here is my code from module_menu():

```
  $items['node/%node/jobs'] = array(
    'title' => 'Jobs',
    'page callback' => 'job_applications_form',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 'node'),
    'access callback' => 'job_applications_user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('site_owner', 1),
    'menu_name' => 'menu-dealer-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
```

The menu's name is menu-dealer-menu. I am using Drupal 6, and upgrading to 7 is not an option right now, and won't be for the next couple of months.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any way to do this in Drupal 6 so I just ended up creating a custom menu and some functions to make it do what I want. If anyone else runs into this problem, just send me a message and I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wildcard in the path `node/%node/jobs`. If you want Drupal to show a menu link, you have to tell it how to figure out the %node argument. You can do it with a function named `node_to_arg`.

The function name, actually, is [wildcard]_to_arg. I suggest you change the wildcard to something different, since there are several menu paths with %node in it. If you relied on node_load to return you a node object, you can just call it from [wildcard]_load.

There is [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/109153#to_arg) on [wildcard]_to_arg and you can see how [user_uid_optional_to_arg](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_uid_optional_to_arg/6) implements it for the `user/%user_uid_optional` path.

Comment: The Pro Drupal Development explains it very clearly, it's where I learned about it. Give it a try.